# Dynamically create a List inside jenkins pipeline on a plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Is there a way in Jenkins pipeline to generate/modify a "list" given to a plugin?

For example, I'm working with the plugin [nexus-artifact-uploader](https://github.com/jenkinsci/nexus-artifact-uploader-plugin).
Sometimes I want to upload `n` configuration files, the other time `n-1` files. Depending of a parameter set by the user.

```
steps {
    nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: [
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'swagger', file: "swagger.json", type: 'json'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-dtr-secret', file: "k8s-dtr-secret.yml", type: 'yml'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-app-secret', file: "k8s-app-secret.yml", type: 'yml'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-deployment', file: "k8s-deployment.yml", type: 'yml'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-autoscaler', file: "k8s-autoscaler.yml", type: 'yml'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-service', file: "k8s-service.yml", type: 'yml'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-ingress', file: "k8s-ingress.yml", type: 'yml']
        ],
        credentialsId: 'my-credentialsId',
        groupId: 'my-groupId',
        nexusUrl: 'my-nexusUrl',
        nexusVersion: 'nexus2',
        protocol: 'http',
        repository: 'my-repository',
        version: "${buildTag}"
}
```

Let's say I don't want tu upload the `k8s-ingress`, because I want my deployement to be local and not accessed outside my namespace in k8s. I'm not famillar with the (groovy?) syntax, but seems to me that it's a `list` of `list` of `map`? Is it possible to dynamically create that list with a for loop for example, or pop an item depending of a value inside?

```
steps {
    def my_artifacts = [
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'swagger', file: "swagger.json", type: 'json'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-dtr-secret', file: "k8s-dtr-secret.yml", type: 'yml'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-app-secret', file: "k8s-app-secret.yml", type: 'yml'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-deployment', file: "k8s-deployment.yml", type: 'yml'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-autoscaler', file: "k8s-autoscaler.yml", type: 'yml'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-service', file: "k8s-service.yml", type: 'yml'],
        [artifactId: "${projectName}", classifier: 'k8s-ingress', file: "k8s-ingress.yml", type: 'yml']
        ]
    if (params.no_istio == True){
      my_artifacts.remove() # Someway to find in my list of list of maps my value for key `file` == "k8s-ingress.yml"
    }

    nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: my_artifacts,
        credentialsId: 'my-credentialsId',
        groupId: 'my-groupId',
        nexusUrl: 'my-nexusUrl',
        nexusVersion: 'nexus2',
        protocol: 'http',
        repository: 'my-repository',
        version: "${buildTag}"
}
```

Comment: You actually have a list of maps, so in your if statement you can use something like: `my_artifacts.removeAll { it.file in (['k8s-ingress.yml','k8s-dtr-secret.yml'])}  `

Comment: Thank you so much for that help. That lambda helps a lot! I was trying to do something like `my_artifacts.remove(IndexOf(something.contains("k8s-ingress.yml")))`

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something to @NoamHelmer 's comment

I could not declare `my_artifacts` inside my steps, I had to declare and modify it outside my `pipeline`.

```
def artifactsList = [
                    [artifactId: "${params.PROJECT_NAME}", classifier: 'swagger', file: "swagger.json", type: 'json'],
                    [artifactId: "${params.PROJECT_NAME}", classifier: 'k8s-dtr-secret', file: "k8s-dtr-secret.yml", type: 'yml'],
                    [artifactId: "${params.PROJECT_NAME}", classifier: 'k8s-app-secret', file: "k8s-app-secret.yml", type: 'yml'],
                    [artifactId: "${params.PROJECT_NAME}", classifier: 'k8s-deployment', file: "k8s-deployment.yml", type: 'yml'],
                    [artifactId: "${params.PROJECT_NAME}", classifier: 'k8s-autoscaler', file: "k8s-autoscaler.yml", type: 'yml'],
                    [artifactId: "${params.PROJECT_NAME}", classifier: 'k8s-service', file: "k8s-service.yml", type: 'yml'],
                    [artifactId: "${params.PROJECT_NAME}", classifier: 'k8s-ingress', file: "k8s-ingress.yml", type: 'yml']
    ]

if (!params.EXPOSE_API_OUTSIDE_K8S) {
    artifactsList.removeAll { it.classifier in (['k8s-ingress'])}
}

pipeline {
    stages {
        stage("My step") {
            steps {
                    nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: my_artifacts,
                            credentialsId: 'my-credentialsId',
                            groupId: 'my-groupId',
                            nexusUrl: 'my-nexusUrl',
                            nexusVersion: 'nexus2',
                            protocol: 'http',
                            repository: 'my-repository',
                            version: "${buildTag}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can define it inside the steps directive but you will need to wrap it in a `script` directive because it is scripted pipeline syntax: `steps { script{ def ...}}`